# PHP - Can't add session variable even after session_start

Tags: php, session

Most of the answers about not adding a session variable have ended in the user finding that the session was not being started.

I'm having an issue where I cannot add a session variable, even after a session_start.

Pertinent code:

login.php

```
<?php 
    require("../common.php"); 
    if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) { 
        echo "true";
        header("Location: dashboard.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to dashboard.php"); 
    } 
    $submitted_username = ''; 
    if(!empty($_POST)) { 
        $info = " SELECT id, username, password, salt, email, access FROM users WHERE username = :username "; 
        $params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($info); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($params); 
        } catch(PDOException $ex)  { 
            die("Failed to run query"); 
        } 
        $login_ok = false; 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)  { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            }  
            if($check_password === $row['password']) { 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 
        if($login_ok) { 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            $_SESSION['access'] = "1";
            header("Location: dashboard.php"); 
            session_write_close();
            die("Redirecting to: dashboard.php"); 
        }  else { 
echo "<div id=\"loginfail\" class=\"gradwin\">\n";
echo "  <p class=\"dark1\">LOGIN FAILURE</p>\n";
echo "</div>\n";
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 
?> 
<div id="loginbox" class="gradwin">
    <p class="darktitle">HITS Login</p> 
    <form action="index.php" method="post" name="formLogin"> 
    <!-- fake fields for Chrome autofill... -->
    <input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusername"/>
    <input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepassword"/>
        <p class="dark1">Username:</p>
        <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <p class="dark1">Password:</p> 
        <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" name="loginForm"><br><br>
    </form> 
    <a class="dark" href="register.php">Register</a>
</div>
```

common.php

```
<?php 

    $username = "MYNAME"; 
    $password = "MYPASS"; 
    $host = "localhost"; 
    $dbname = "MYDB"; 
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 

    try { 
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); 
    } catch(PDOException $ex) { 
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
    session_start();
```

I am being redirected to the dashboard.php page, so I know there is a session started.  The session_start is in the common.php file.  I have placed...

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

...in the dashboard.php file.  I can see all the pertinent user data, but not the access data.  My array echoes as follows:

```
array(1) {
  ["user"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "11"
    ["username"]=>
    string(2) "ba"
    ["email"]=>
    string(9) "ba@ba.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `session_start()`? Are these files on the same (sub)domain?

Comment: The common file is outside of the webroot, which is one level higher than my login.php and dashboard.php files.

Comment: What does `common.php` look like, are you perhaps setting `$_SESSION['user']` manually there?

Comment: You're just assuming session_start() succeeded. check its return value. if it's false, then the session DIDN'T start.

Answer (score 2):

Your sending out headers before calling `session_start()`. `session_start()` must go before any headers are sent:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
session_start();
```

should be

```
session_start(); 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Or, better yet, just move it to the top of the file.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well, but then `if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {` and the header redirect in there would not work, or would they?

Comment: It shouldn't work. But I'm out of ideas. I'd like to see if they provide feedback on this so we can find out for sure.

Comment: That did not change anything, unfortunately.  I left it up top in my common.php file for best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding session_write_close() before your redirect / location header.  I've noticed that in some cases a redirect can cause the session not to be written properly.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, calls to `die()` or `exit()` will stop the session data from being stored. Other shutdown functions and destructors will be fired, but not `session_write_close()`

you'll either need to run `session_write_close()` before `die()` or rewrite that part to not use `die()`.

a little more info here. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49462&edit=1

Comment: I took the die statements out, as there is nothing to hide on the login.php page.  That still did not solve anything.  I have expanded my code snippet above, so hopefully someone sees something outside of the ordinary now.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid error!!!

I had two versions of my login.php file on the server.  One was called inc_login.php, which I was modifying.  The index.php was looking at the other.  One I got that straightened out, things worked perfectly.

Anyone else having an impossible issue, please note: you are probably doing something dumb like me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code over here :

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $_SESSION['access'] = "1";
    header("Location: dashboard.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to dashboard.php"); 
}
```

I think the error lies on the if statement which runs the code within the curly brackets. You've initiated the code to run only if the session variable 'user' is not empty which is perfectly fine. However you've never set a variable for  it so therefore the code never sets the session variable 'access' to store the input 1 hence the array is dumping empty session variables.

Try this :

```
<?php 
require("../common.php"); 


    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $_SESSION['access'] = "1";
        header("Location: dashboard.php"); 
        die("Redirecting to dashboard.php"); 
    }
```